# Gaussian filter with uneven sampled data

Tags: r, filter, gaussian

I have a time series which is unevenly sampled and I want to downsample it to 20Hz. I have made a moving average by binning the data points when in 0.05s time windows (20Hz) and applying an arithmetic mean to it. The data frame looks like this:

```
          Time    Right     Left
1  0.000000000 18.21980 30.98789
2  0.009222031 22.15157 37.18590
3  0.022511959 25.63218 42.49231
4  0.029854059 28.43851 46.57811
5  0.039320946 30.43885 49.29414
6  0.052499056 31.60561 50.67852
7  0.059612036 32.01045 50.92879
8  0.076606989 31.80335 50.34975
9  0.082647085 31.18134 49.29151
10 0.090698957 30.35415 48.09110
```

And the code I used for the moving average was this:

```
data$group_num <- floor(data$Time/0.05)

data2<-NULL

data2$Right = aggregate(data$Right,
                               list(group_num=data$group_num), mean)
data2$Left = aggregate(data$Left,
                                     list(group_num=data$group_num), mean)
data2$Time = aggregate(data$Time,
                                 list(group_num=data$group_num), mean)
```

However, for optimizing it I want to make rather a Gaussian filter so that the data points in the middle of the bin have more weight. I couldnt find any function that could deal with uneven sampling. Thus, I started writting a script, where I managed to give them weights.

```
data$weight <- ((data$Time-data$group_num*0.05)*((data$group_num+1)*0.05-data$Time))^5
```

I have to normalize these weights by the mean of the weights in their own bin (for instance). By trying to normalize these weights to the mean of their own group I ran into problems with too slow functions. Could anybody give me a hand with it??

Comment: I would suggest to look at `rollmean` and `rollapply` functions of the `zoo` package

Comment: If I understood right, these functions work with a fixed number of data points for the binning. This is how every function I have seen so far work. However, because my sampling is uneven I bin them according to time windows, some of them have 3 data points, other 4 or 5 or 6....

Comment: OK, then would  `data.table` be an option for you?

Comment: I have been trying some functions of data.table but I still can´t come up with a function that could help me with that. The main problem I have is that after finding a weight (there are different ways) I need a normalization so that I can multiply that weight for the Time, Right, Left. The problem is that for normalizing I make a new table, because the lengh is equal to the max(group_num) and not the length of the the original data frame. Once at that point I´m stuck, just manage to do it in a very inefficient way

Comment: I had in mind something like `data.table(data)[,group_num:=floor(Time/.05),][,weight:=((Time-group_num*0.05)*((group_num+1)*0.05-Time))^5][,list(Right=mean(Right*weight/sum(weight)),Left=mean(Left*weight/sum(weight))),group_num][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do what I wanted. The key function that helped me to overcome this one was ave(). Thank god. So this is what I basically did:

```
data$weight <- (abs(data$Time-(data$group_num*0.05+0.025)))^(-1)

data$Norm<-ave(data$weight,data$group_num,FUN=function(x) x/sum(x))

data$Time2<- data$Time*data$Norm

data$Right2<- data$Right*data$Norm

data$Left2<- data$Left*data$Norm

data2$Time<- tapply(data$Time2, data$group_num, sum)

data2$Right<- tapply(data$Right2, data$group_num, sum)

data2$Left<- tapply(data$Left2, data$group_num, sum)
```

Thanks Marat Talipov for the help. From what I see in your code this could also work. But because this is just working fine and quick enough I will stay with this.